# How to access a website by IP address at AWS Opsworks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ip, unicorn, aws-opsworks

I have many apps deployed per instance at AWS Opsworks. Each app has a domain or subdomain assigned to it.

It works fine when I type the domain/subdomain in the address bar in a web browser.

Although I would like to know how to access the domain/subdomain using the IP address in the address bar?

```
    Eg: 
http://[IP_ADDRESS]/[SOME_STRING_TO_ACCESS_DOMAIN_OR_SUBDOMAIN_1.COM]
http://[IP_ADDRESS]/[SOME_STRING_TO_ACCESS_MY_DOMAIN_OR_SUBDOMAIN_2.COM]
http://[IP_ADDRESS]/[SOME_STRING_TO_ACCESS_MY_DOMAIN_OR_SUBDOMAIN_3.COM]
http://[IP_ADDRESS]/[SOME_STRING_TO_ACCESS_MY_DOMAIN_OR_SUBDOMAIN_4.COM]
```

The web server is 'nginx' + 'unicorn'. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the ip as a server name to the server, eg:

```
server {
  server_name example.com 11.22.33.44;
  # ...
}
```

If you want to handle the string after the ip in a different way, like `ip/domain_name` you need a separate server to handle this

```
server {
  server_name 11.22.33.44;
  root /path/to/root/$uri; # for example
  # ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The same IP address serves more than one subdomain. I would like to know how to access a subdomain via IP address.